# wrong order of mixed textual and graphical output in the final output document

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Within a for loop I decide to create some graphics and related tables.

The tables are created with `writeLines()` and `print()`.

For creating the graphics I use `plot()`, `boxplot()`, `mtext()`, `text()`, `axis()`. 
So one graphic is created in many steps. Each graphic for it self is complete and nice.

My problem is:
when I knit the markdown document in Rstudio the graphics and tables are not in the correct place. 
The first graphic is shown at the place, where the second should be or a little before, after `cor.test.default()` tells me a warning. Definitively it is shown during the next pass of the for loop.

### Conclusion of the Problem

Creating textual output in adition to graphics is mixed up under special circumstances

For reproducing the problem I create some data
All the computations are collected in the "workingChunk"

For demonstrating the problem I use the chunk "loops" at the end.
So read the last chunk first

In the second loop the FIRST graphic is placed in the output 
during the SECOND passage of the loop, after the function cor.test() comes up with the warning.

As well the SECOND graphic is placed in the output 
during the THIRD passage of the loop, after the function cor.test() comes up with the warning.
and so on.

I found a workarround for this problem but it is not really handy:
When I replace the for loop with single chunk-calls, then the output is in the correct order.

So I'm sure that the reason for the problem is the interaction of the for loop and the function cor.test()

Here is the Example-code (about 140 lines):

````
---
title: "Test graphic & textual output"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: 
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

```

```{r creatingData, echo=TRUE}
### {r creatingData, echo=TRUE}
# creating some data
a.df <- data.frame(height=c(1:19),
                   width=c(21:39)*10,
                   depht=c(41:59)*20,
                   group=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3))
a.df$groupF <- as.factor(a.df$group)

Vars <- names(a.df)[c(1:3)]
```

```{r workingChunk, echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
    cat("\n===================================================================\n",
        "following the calculations for:\n",
        "YVar:",YVar, "\n Group:", "group", "\n")

    # Daten für Auswertung extrahieren
    selvar <- c("group","groupF", YVar)

    # Datensätze mit Fehlwerten in der Zielvariablen ausschließen!
    a.sub <- a.df[ complete.cases(a.df[ , selvar]), selvar]   

    # print(str(a.sub))

    ## Tabelle für gruppierte Zielgrößen
    mT <- table(a.sub[ , c("groupF", YVar)])
    print(ftable(addmargins(mT)))  ## absolute Häufigkeiten
    writeLines("\n")

    if (runCorTest) {
        ## calculating Spearmans correlation
        myCorTest <- try(cor.test(a.sub[["group"]], a.sub[[YVar]], 
                              method = "spearman", alternative = "two.sided" ))

        print(myCorTest)
        writeLines("\n")
    }

## preparing the grafic
     GL.x1 <- levels(a.sub[["groupF"]])  ## grouplabels

     # Calculating the range of Y
     my.ylim <- c(min(a.sub[[YVar]], na.rm = TRUE), max(a.sub[[YVar]], na.rm = TRUE))

     at.x <- c(1:length(GL.x1))    ## Labelpositionen anlegen
     G.data <- vector("list", length(GL.x1))    ## Vektoren für die Daten der Gruppen anlegen

     # Daten der Gruppen herausziehen 
     G.data <- split(a.sub[[YVar]], a.sub["groupF"])
     # print(str(G.data))

## drawing emtpy plot
     cat("\n\n>>> Here should be placed the Grafik for:",YVar, "<<<\n")
     plot( x = NA, y = NA, type = "n",
           main = YVar,
           xlim = c( 1, length( GL.x1)) + c( -0.6, 0.6),
           ylim = my.ylim, 
           xlab = NA, ylab = NA,
           axes = FALSE, frame.plot = TRUE)

     # X-axis 
     axis( 1, las = 1, labels = FALSE)
     mtext(GL.x1, at = at.x, cex=0.8, side = 1, line = .3)

     # Y-axis
     axis( 2, las = 1)

## drawing the data 
     for (i in 1:length(G.data)){
        boxplot(G.data[i], # col = "white",
                 at = at.x[i], range = 0, add = TRUE,
                 boxwex = 0.6, yaxs = "i", axes = FALSE)
     }

```

```{r, loops, echo=FALSE}
 cat("\n===================================================================",
    "\n===================================================================\n",
    "calling the workingChunk within a for loop without executing cor.test()",
    "\n works fine!!",
    "\n===================================================================",
    "\n===================================================================\n")

runCorTest <- FALSE
for ( YVar in Vars) {
  <<workingChunk>>
}


cat("\n===================================================================",
    "\n===================================================================\n",
    "calling the workingChunk within a for loop with executing cor.test() ",
    "\n mixes up the textual output and the graphics!!",
    "\n===================================================================",
    "\n===================================================================\n")

runCorTest <- TRUE
for ( YVar in Vars) {
  <<workingChunk>>
}


cat("\n===================================================================",
    "\n===================================================================\n",
    "calling the workingChunk with executing cor.test() ",
    "\n workarround without a for loop works fine!!",
    "\n===================================================================",
    "\n===================================================================\n")

runCorTest <- TRUE
YVar <- Vars[1] 
<<workingChunk>>

YVar <- Vars[2] 
<<workingChunk>>

YVar <- Vars[3] 
<<workingChunk>>

```
````

Comment: Which output format do you use? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Now I created a minimal reproducible example. But how can I attache the file with the example to this post?

Comment: You can [edit] your question and include the verbatim source code. Don't forget proper formatting.

Comment: the RMD-file has about 160 lines of code. I don't think it is usefull to include so much code in my question.

Comment: It is useful if all these lines are necessary to reproduce the issue. That's why it says **minimal** reproducible example.

Comment: You have three output formats specified. Are all of them affected?

Comment: Yes, all three output formats are affected!

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer but a much shorter test case and a workaround:

````
---
title: "Test graphic & textual output"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  word_document: default 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
foo <- function(letter, warn) {
    cat("Doing", letter, "\n")
    print(letter)
    if (warn) warning(letter)
    cat("Graphic for", letter, "goes here", "\n")
    plot(1, main = letter)
}
```

# with loop and with warning

```{r}
for (letter in letters[1:3])
    foo(letter, TRUE)
```

# with loop and without warning

```{r}
for (letter in letters[1:3])
    foo(letter, FALSE)
```

# without loop and with warning

```{r}
foo("a", TRUE)
foo("b", TRUE)
foo("c", TRUE)
```

# with loop and with suppressed warning

```{r warning=FALSE}
for (letter in letters[1:3])
    foo(letter, TRUE)
```
````

Besides removing all of the data processing, I have also switched from a named chunk to a function, which I find more idiomatic in R. That does not change the strange ordering, though.

If the warning message is not important in your case, you can use the workaround shown in the end: Suppressing the warning with the chunk option `warning=FALSE` restores the ordering.